# What can cause dictionary.ContainsKey(dictionary.Keys.First()) to return false?

Tags: c#, dictionary, equals, gethashcode

`dictionary.Keys.First().GetHashCode() == dictionary.Keys.First().GetHashCode()` returns true
`dictionary.Keys.First() == dictionary.Keys.First()` returns true

What's missing?  Why can't the dictionary find this object?

Type of dictionary: `Dictionary<ExceptionWrapper<Exception>, List<int>>`.

Here is the implementation of `ExceptionWrapper.Equals` and `ExceptionWrapper.GetHashCode`:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return (typeof(TException).FullName + exception.Message + exception.StackTrace).GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj) {
  return 
    obj is ExceptionWrapper<TException>
&& (obj as ExceptionWrapper<TException>).GetHashCode() == GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `dictionary`? A code snippet would probably help as well.

Comment: Is `dictionary` being accessed from different threads? What is the key type? Does it override `Equals` inconsistently with the definition of `GetHashCode`?

Comment: There's no multithreading going on.

Comment: It's not a good style to create hash from a concatenated `string`. Your `Equals` is also very wrong; it returns `true` if two hashes are equal by accident. These are just comments, not the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on equals.  Yes, it is sloppy.  I'd say I was in a hurry before but that's not a real excuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was first added to the `Dictionary<,>` when it had one hash code. After that the object was "mutated" to give a state where the hash code is some new number.

The `Dictionary<,>` is therefore in an invalid state.

Do not mutate an object that might be a key in some hashtable somewhere, in a way the changes the hash code of that object.

Comment: I don't /think/ there's any mutation going on.  I'm going to try storing the hashcode in memory and see if it resolves the issue to be sure.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: If it was because of a state mutation, why doesn't `dictionary.containsKey(dictionary.Keys.First())` return true?

Comment: This seems like the most likely suspect... ContainsKey checks only the  hashcode bucket from the object... so if the hashcode changes it is now looking in the wrong bucket for the object.

Comment: @MushinNoShin Because the `Dictionary<,>` is completely corrupted when hash codes change. The key is ***lost***. Search for the key takes place in only one "bucket", the one corresponding to the new hash, but nothing is found since the item is located in another bucket.

Comment: That was it, thank you.  Now I get to try to figure out how that exception changed.

Comment: @MushinNoShin If an exception being handled in a `catch` block is rethrown with the `throw` statement later in the block, that rethrow will modify the stack trace of the exception.